# HTTP query parsed, value read from JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get the following JSON from a HTTP query:

`{"ActuatorNumber":"2","Direction":"right","Speed":"45"}`

The following code fails to execute:

`Servo.writeReg((o.ActuatorNumber*2)-1, o.Speed);`

`writeReg` comes from the [MRAA](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/node/) library.
The query is send as following (using `curl`):

`"ActuatorNumber=2&Direction=right&Speed=45"`

It seems like every value of `o` is read incorrectly. Could there be a parsing error which isn't visible when printed?

The parsing is done as following:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);
var parsedQuery = JSON.stringify(url_parsed.query);
```

`parsedQuery` is later given to the appropriate function as argument `o`.

Error:

`Error: in method 'I2c_writeReg', argument 2 of type 'uint8_t'`

Comment: Why don't you console log `o` and find out? It looks like a string to me?

Comment: @adeneo The first codeblock is the result from `console.log(o)`.

Comment: Are you trying to convert `{"ActuatorNumber":"2","Direction":"right","Speed":"45"}` to `"ActuatorNumber=2&Direction=right&Speed=45"`?

Comment: @AnotherDev I'm trying to get the `2` from `ActuatorNumber`, multiply it with `2` and subtract `1`.

Comment: What is console.log(typeof o)?

Comment: @AnotherDev It's a string. It's starting to dawn on me I'm doing it terribly wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the line `var parsedQuery = JSON.stringify(url_parsed.query);`. `JSON.stringify` is used to convert a value to a JSON string.

Comment: No, you were close, you just need to parse `o` into an object. I just posted an answer.

Comment: Oh God no! You don't need to parse it into an object, `url.parse` already **returns** an object, all you have to do is stop stringifying it.

Comment: @adeneo Fails with the same error I posted under AnotherDev's answer.

Comment: I agree @adeneo, I didn't realize the order of how things we're getting called.

Comment: That error comes from somewhere else, you'd have to post that code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @adeneo said, just don't use `JSON.stringify`.

You'll then also need to parse o.Speed to an int, as the function is expecting an int.

```
Servo.writeReg((o.ActuatorNumber*2)-1, parseInt(o.Speed));
```

Comment: I recommend that you set a base on `parseInt`. In this case, you should use `parseInt(o.Speed, 10)`.